# I am getting error when use start command in symfony

Tags: symfony

I am very new to Symfony. I have installed Symfony in my system with `symfony demo` command it's working fine. I installed in that folder already developed project code. when use `php bin/console server:start 0.0.0.0:8000` this command I am getting error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: The autoloader expected class "AppKernel" to be defined in file "/home/Desktop/commercetools-sunrise-php-master/vendor/composer/../../app/AppKernel.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo. in /home/Desktop/commercetools-sunrise-php-master/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php:223
>    Stack trace:#0 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader->loadClass('AppKernel')#1 /home/Desktop/commercetools-sunrise-php-master/bin/console(26): spl_autoload_call('AppKernel')#2 {main}
>     thrown in /home/Desktop/commercetools-sunrise-php-master/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php on line 223

Any one can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error, I tried your steps and it work very well. "I installed in that folder already developed project code" you could explain that?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Server is running when I run this command " php -S 10.10.90.15:8000 -t web/ web/index.php " . when I run in browser i will get error

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/Desktop/commercetools-sunrise-php-master/app/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/nyros/Desktop/commercetools-sunrise-php-master/app/autoload.php on line 14

Comment: Yes I got solution, now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

There may be a corrupted generated PHP file. Try this :

```
composer run-script post-install-cmd
```